# view content of database in textfield

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

below is the code which i made to insert an integer value into database. this code is to help the user to keep track of his/her account balance. in this code the content of the database is displayed as a toast message on button click. i want the content to be displayed in a text field when this activity is called. the textfield to display the content and the update button are on the same activity. so when the user enters the value to be added or subtracted from the database and when the update button is pressed the textfield should be refreshed with the updated value. plz make the sufficient changes in the code.

thank you

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com.sqltut;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button save,load,deposit,withdraw;
EditText balance,updatevalue;
DataHandler handler; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    load=(Button) findViewById(R.id.load);
    deposit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.deposit);
    withdraw=(Button) findViewById(R.id.withdraw);
    balance=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.balance);
    updatevalue=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.updatevalue);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String getbalance=balance.getText().toString();
            int bal=Integer.parseInt(getbalance);
            handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
            handler.open();
            long id=handler.insertData(bal);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handler.close();
        }
    });

    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int getbalance;
            getbalance=0;
            handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
            handler.open();
            Cursor C=handler.returnData();
            if(C.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                getbalance=C.getInt(0); 
                }while(C.moveToNext());
            }
            handler.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Balance:"+getbalance,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    withdraw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String updt=updatevalue.getText().toString();
        int value=Integer.parseInt(updt);
        int flag=0;
        handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
        handler.open();
        handler.updateData(value,flag);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.close();
        }
    });

    deposit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String updt=updatevalue.getText().toString();
        int value=Integer.parseInt(updt);
        int flag=1;
        handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
        handler.open();
        handler.updateData(value,flag);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.close();
        }
    });
    //to call next activity
    Button createAppointment = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
    createAppointment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);            
        }
    });
    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**DataHandler.java**

```
package com.sqltut;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataHandler {

public static final String BALANCE="balance";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME="mydatabase";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table mytable(balance integer not null);";

DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
Context ctx;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public DataHandler(Context ctx)
{ 
    this.ctx = ctx;
    dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
}

private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     try{
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
     }
     catch(SQLException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable ");
         onCreate(db);
    }

}
public DataHandler open()
{
    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertData(Integer balance)
{
    ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
    content.put(BALANCE, balance);
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, content);

}

public void updateData(Integer value,Integer flag)
{
    db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "select balance from  " + TABLE_NAME ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int current = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            current=  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

    }
    if(flag==0){
            current = current-value;
    }else {
            current = current+value ; 
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    try{
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String rawQuery = "update mytable set balance="+current;
        db.execSQL(rawQuery);
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Cursor returnData()
{
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {BALANCE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a method in database like this.

```
  public int getValue(){

  //get present value from your crud operations
  //you have to relate with CRUD values and get the int value
   //call the method to get you required value, ex; If delete operation is done then you have give updated value to this method or insert is done then you have to call this method and you have to send the updated value to this, similarly you have to do this for update operation also. then you will get the value into this method whether any operation has done on database.
  }
```

step1:call the method from you button click.
step2:inside getValue() invoke each crud method to get updated value.
try in this way.
call the method in the onClick of Button.
hope this may helps you

Comment: could you write the entire code there. since im new to android coding that would be more helpful.